# How can I create dynamic Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, expression, lambda

I have a question, how do I add another filter and this I have to validate that was selected?

```cs
private Expression < Func < Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool >> Filter() {
    var dateStart = dtpDateStart.Value.Date;
    var dateEnd = dtpDateEnd.Value.Date;

    Expression < Func < Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool >> expr = null;

    expr = f = > f.DatFlux >= dateStart.Date && f.DatFlux <= dateEnd.Date;

    if (txtDescription.Text != String.Empty) {
        //add filter
    }

    return expr;
}
```

**Update:** I'll use the expression in this function:

```cs
public virtual IQueryable < T > Filter(Expression < Func < T, bool >> expressao) {
    return DbSet.Where(expressao).AsQueryable < T > ();
}
```

What I was trying to do is this but with an Expression

```cs
public List < Users > GetUsers(int ? id, string name) {
    using(DBContext ctx = new DBContext()) {
        IQueryable query = ctx.Usuarios;
        if (id.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(x = > x.ID == id);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            query = query.Where(x = > x.Name.StartsWith(name));

        return query.ToList();

    }
}
```

Comment: please tag this with your programming language.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to pass back another Expression with your statement or you are trying to embed lambda expressions? I'm not understanding exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm trying to embed lambda expressions.

Comment: Okay, if that's the case, then I provided an example of an embedded lambda statement. But I'm not sure what you are expecting as a returning value, so I don't know how you'd like to modify your example.

Comment: I add update how I'll use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inherit from [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323984.aspx)

```cs
public class MyVisitor: ExpressionVisitor
{
    private LambdaExpression visitor;
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression, LambdaExpression visitor)
    {
        this.visitor = visitor;
        return Visit(expression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
    {
        var binary = visitor.Body as BinaryExpression;

        return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, b, binary, b.IsLiftedToNull, b.Method);
    }
}
```

your `Filter()` method might look like this

```cs
    private Expression<Func<Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool>> Filter()
    {
        var dateStart = dtpDateStart.Value.Date;
        var dateEnd = dtpDateEnd.Value.Date;
        var description = txtDescription.Text;

        Expression<Func<Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool>> expr = null;

        expr = f => f.DatFlux >= dateStart.Date && f.DatFlux <= dateEnd.Date;

        if (description != String.Empty)
        {
            //add filter
            Expression<Func<Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool>> other = f => f.Description == description;

            var modifier = new MyVisitor();
            expr = (Expression<Func<Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool>>)modifier.Modify((Expression)expr, (LambdaExpression)other);
        }

        return expr;
    }
```

[example](https://gist.github.com/axrwkr/5200097)

have a look at the following for more information

[How to: Modify Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx)

Comment: Return error {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: right"}

Comment: return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.AndAlso, b, binary, b.IsLiftedToNull, b.Method);

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a demo of your requirements, then you can create and modify [`Expression Trees`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) using the [`System.Linq.Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) namespace.

However, in the case of your question, it would probably be easier to use EF:

```
bool filterDescription = !String.IsNullOrEmpty( txtDescription.Text );

expr = f =>
  (
    ( f.DatFlux >= dateStart.Date && f.DatFlux <= dateEnd.Date )
    &&
    ( !filterDescription || ... add filter ... )
  )
;
```

or normal C#:

```
if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( txtDescription.Text ) )
{
  expr = f => f.DatFlux >= dateStart.Date && f.DatFlux <= dateEnd.Date;
}
else
{
  expr = f => f.DatFlux >= dateStart.Date && f.DatFlux <= dateEnd.Date
    &&
    ... add filter ...
  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well here is a sample on how to embed lambda statements. It's not your example, but here ya go:

```
Func<int, int, EventHandler> makeHandler =
    (dx, dy) => (sender, e) => {
        var btn = (Button) sender;
        btn.Top += dy;
        btn.Left += dx;
    };

btnUp.Click += makeHandler(0, -1);
btnDown.Click += makeHandler(0, 1);
btnLeft.Click += makeHandler(-1, 0);
btnRight.Click += makeHandler(1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[It is simple.Visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505)

the tricky thing is invoking the `OrderByAlias` - using `MakeGenericMethod` may be the way, as shown in the link above.

Comment: I would not classify expression trees as "simple"... (also: this answer should probably be a comment, IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
private Expression<Func<Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool>> Filter()
{
    var dateStart = dtpDateStart.Value.Date;
    var dateEnd = dtpDateEnd.Value.Date;

    Func<Entity.Modelos.Flux, bool> expr = null;

    expr = f => f.DatFlux >= dateStart.Date && f.DatFlux <= dateEnd.Date;

    if(txtDescription.Text != String.Empty)
    {
       expr = f => expr(f) && f.Title.Equals(txtDescription.Text); // ← Your additional filter
    }

    return f => expr(f);
}
```

Comment: Get error "The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"